# apt-get update failed to fetch

Tags: 14.04, apt, updates

I am trying to do an update and am getting the following error. Could anyone help on a solution. My kernel will not update because of this

```
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/psyke83/ppa/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/psyke83/ppa/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PPA that you are trying to upgrade packages from (found [here](https://launchpad.net/~psyke83/+archive/ubuntu/ppa)) hasn't been updated for 5 years. It does not provide packages for your 14.04 version of Ubuntu.

You should get rid of the PPA, e.g. by installing `ppa-purge` and doing

`sudo ppa-purge ppa:psyke83/ppa`

Then do `sudo apt-get update`.

Then, `sudo apt-get upgrade` will remove the packages from this PPA, and install your new kernel.

Comment: is this the command sudo ppa-purge ppa.launchpad.net/psyke83/ppa/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages
I done this and done update but still same issue

Comment: I added the PPA to my system, and used ppa-purge to remove it. I edited my answer with the exact command above.

Comment: Thank you but I ran that purge command and this is what happened             Updating packages lists
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/psyke83/ppa/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/psyke83/ppa/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
Warning:  apt-get update failed for some reason
PPA to be removed: psyke83 ppa
Warning:  Could not find package list for PPA: psyke83 ppa

Comment: Manually remove `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/psyke83-ubuntu-ppa-trusty.list` and retry.